# Documentation page rolling back by a single user

Tags: support, feature-request

I just received a notification of a proposed change to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/133180?draftId=118798) documentation.

However, this was not a "proposed" change at all because the user has the authority to 'make this change without review'.

I've created a topic in this field called: `Uploading files` and adjusted bit by bit, but this rollback includes the change of every topic, including the one I've wrote word by word.

Obviously, I've rejected the change (but if it gets accepted is out of my hands) but the reason why I'm asking is why a single user has the authority to rollback an entire page of topics.

I can understand rolling back a specific topic, but *not* the entire page?? Shouldn't this at least be reviewed by more people, no matter what the user rank is?

I do not have the privileges to roll back, approve or disprove such edits and this would be out of my league, but I would highly disapprove of such monotone mechanics on a broad scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies; the change I rolled back was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/132686?filter-tags=php), which was plagiarized from [this site](https://www.lynda.com/PHP-tutorials/Cross-site-scripting-XSS/133321/180303-4.html). I did not realize that doing so was taking out other content with it.

I've re-added your changes to that section, and will be more careful with this in the future.

Comment: Much appreciated, while it resolves the specific issue at hand it does not approach the bigger picture. We all make mistakes, even I do and I do *not* blame you for trying to do the *right* thing. Quick resolution is also understandable with the huge backlog this site has. My aim is more on how an entire documentation page can be rolled back by a single user, again a topic is unstandable.